# xml.etree.ElementTree search tag by variable

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a problem with the xml.etree.ElementTree Module in Python. I tried to search for a tag in the XML Tree using a variable:

```
i = "Http_Https"
print(xmldoc_ports.findall(".//*application-set/[name=i]/application/"))
```

But it looks like that it did not resolve the variable `i`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 223, in <module>
    print(xmldoc_ports.findall(".//*application-set/[name=i]/application/"))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 749, in findall
    return self._root.findall(path, namespaces)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 390, in findall
    return ElementPath.findall(self, path, namespaces)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 293, in findall
    return list(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 263, in iterfind
    selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementPath.py", line 224, in prepare_predicate
    raise SyntaxError("invalid predicate")
```

Is it possible to use a variable in the findall function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.//*application-set/[name=i]/application/` is not valid. I think you meant:

```
xpath = ".//application-set[@name='%s']/application" % i
print(xmldoc_ports.findall(xpath))
```

Note that `@` before the name - this is how you show access the `name` attribute. Also, I've removed the `/` after the `application-set` and `*` before it.

Also, in order to have variable `i` inside the XPath, you should/can use string formatting. The `%s` is a placeholder for `%` operator to fill.

Comment: Thats it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

just as an addendum: If more than one variable is to be replaced, enclose them in `()` parenthesis with comma separator:

```
x = document.findall("".//application-set[@name='%s']/application[@method='%s']" % (i, j)"
```